# How to submit a form when enter key is pressed in an input?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

How can I modify my `q-input` so when I press `enter key` in it, it will submit the `q-form` instead of go in a new line ? Thank you ! :)

```
<q-form ref="urlForm" greedy @submit="saveUrl">
  <q-card-section>
    <!-- url -->
    <q-input
      v-model="url"
      :label="t('url')"
      :rules="[urlValidator]"
      outlined dense autogrow autofocus
    ></q-input>
  </q-card-section>
  <q-card-section class="text-center q-ma-none q-py-md">
    <q-btn class="q-ma-xs" type="submit" color="positive" :loading="saving" :disable="saving">{{ t('SaveChanges') }}</q-btn>
  </q-card-section>
</q-form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad this is because of the `autogrow` in `q-input`.